# What is the trick with 0dip layout_height or layouth_width?

Tags: android, layout, height

I mean why anybody want they view to be 0dip height ?
I have seen this many times, there must be some kind of trick, but I do not get it.

```
        <TextView android:gravity="top" android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contactName"></TextView>
```

Why they don't use for example wrap_content ? what do they want to achieve ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is usually used when having many views inside a linearlayout and have set android:layout_weight="1" in order both views to take equal space. for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In that case, the view will take as much height as all other views.

Comment: Yes, I usually set 0dip width or height in this case. Or you could use it to hide widgets, however the visibility attribute should be used in that case.

Answer (score 26):

This is heavily used for views withing `LinearLayout`. There are three "layout" attributes that `LinearLayout` is aware of:

1. `android:layout_height`
2. `android:layout_width`
3. `android:layout_weight`

You can find example with `android:layout_weight` in [tutorial project](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html).

So when `android:layout_weight` is used on `View` X and `LinearLayout` is horizontal, then X's `android:layout_width` is simply ignored.

Similar, when `android:layout_weight` is used on `View` X and `LinearLayout` is vertical, then X's `android:layout_height` is ignored.

This actually means, that you can put anything in those ignored fields: `0dp` or `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`. It doesn't matter. But it's recommended to use `0dp` so `View`'s do not do extra calculation of their height or width (which is then ignored). This small trick simply saves CPU cycles.

Comment: this is incorrect . try using different weights (for example 1,2,3)  and see that there is a difference between using match_parent and 0px (or 0dp)

Comment: @androiddeveloper, can you elaborate on this a bit? Why does this happen? Can you link to documentation/other references on the subject if possible?

Comment: @batbrat I don't remember where I read about this. However, you can just try it out and see for yourself. you can also read what Lint suggests about this, as it's bad for the performance of the LinearLayout.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I was hoping for an official word rather than experimental verification of a change in layout based on 0dp versus match_parent etc. I'm aware that using a non-zero value will cause cause extra calculations that are best avoided for performance reasons. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @batbrat sorry. I just don't remember. maybe i didn't even read about it but just noticed it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, thanks! I'll try it out and look around. I really appreciate your helping out.

Answer (score 2):

The `android:layout_height="0dp"` is used in various codes because:

1. It means the height of the view can be changed later due to other layout constraints.
2. It is a common practice and often seen in relative and linear layouts.

e.g:

```
android:layout_height = "0dp"
android:layout_weight = "1.0"
```

Height or width when set to "0dp", are mostly used in combination with "weight". e.g. you want to fill all the available space for height then use the above code and like wise the same case for width.