# How can i show image and text view according to my idea?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android and want show something with this plan:
[image]

and my xml file is this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    >
            <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but when run my app,i see like this:
[image]

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

i change XML file but so not work!,my complete xml file after change:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myLIST"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.nothing.myapplication.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: use weight for both of views

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz please post your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st figure is your requirement. So i will first answer what would be the best way to achieve your desired result. Using `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` would be recommended in this case. Then you should use `layout_weight` attribute for your `ImageView` and `TextView` along with `layout_height="0dp"`. Note that `TextView` automatically scrolls vertically so you don't really need `ScrollView`.

Do something like this.

```
          <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"  
                android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />

          <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220491/2319542) for a better understanding.

So finally you do something like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material">

        </ImageView>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

However if your `TextView` doesn't scroll automatically , use `ScrollView` as mentioned in other answers by setting `layout_weight` and `layout_height` attributes.

Comment: Where do you want to show the listview? After the textview?

Comment: listview show any data in fullscreen mode,and when user click one item of listview,listview invisibile,and image and textview visible,and show explain that item .

Comment: Make listview visible by default using `android:visibility="visible"` and linearlayout `gone` using `android:visibility="gone"`.Then programatically inside your `onItemClickListener` of your `ListView` alter the visibility using `linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. However there are better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks,but in linearlayout.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE) error :can not resolve linearlayour.

Comment: `LinearLayout linearlayout;
linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin_layout);
linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace xml file with this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        background="color_code"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout with weights:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />
        <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2">
        <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL" />

        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i get this error:            Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_width less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Using 0dp as the width in a horizontal LinearLayout with weights is a useful trick to ensure that only the weights (and not the intrinsic sizes) are used when sizing the children.  However, if you use 0dp for the opposite dimension, the view will be invisible. This can happen if you change the orientation of a layout without also flipping the 0dp dimension in all the children.

Comment: for this line:android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Please add the attribute android:orientation="vertical" to your LinearLayout-attributes. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">

            </ImageView>
            <ScrollView 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3.5"
                        >
                <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:text="Large Text"
                            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as I am able to get proper output as you needed.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" 
    android:background="@color/blue">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7" 
    android:background="@color/orange">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TestView" />
</LinearLayout>
```