# Align TextView widths in different LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xml-layout

I have this interface:

[image]

Using the below fragment XML. ***Is it possible to align the widths of the TextViews so they are all the same width?***

For example, ODOMETER appears to be the longest word in a textview. How can I adjust all the other TextView's widths to match ODOMETERS? That way they all line up and the interface would be neater.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.VehicleFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewVehicle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- YEAR -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="YEAR"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editYear"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- MAKE -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="MAKE"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editMake"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- MODEL -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="MODEL"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editModel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- BODY -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="BODY"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editBody"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- COLOR -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="COLOR"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- TAG -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="TAG"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- STATE -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="STATE"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editState"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Odometer -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="ODOMETER"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editOdometer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- VIN -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="VIN"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editVIN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="17"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnScanVIN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:text="SCAN"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_WHITE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Other -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="OTHER"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editOther"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Consider using a `GridLayout`. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. You're using a horizontal layout for every couple of label-text field. Do as follow:

1. add `android:weightSum="z"` to every LinearLayout
2. add `android:layout_weight="0.y"` to every Label
3. add `android:layout_weight="0.x"` to every Text Field

Note that 0.x + 0.y must equals to z. Obviously you need to set number values.

---

**EDIT**:
This code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.VehicleFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewVehicle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- YEAR -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="YEAR"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editYear"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- MAKE -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="MAKE"
                    android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editMake"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Works great and I get this result [image]

Comment: That doesn't work. I used 0.2 for the TV and 0.8 for the ET. I added 1 to the sum for each LL

Comment: set width to `math_parent` on both ETs and Labels

Comment: `<TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
I can see a 0dp

Comment: 0dp is equivalent to match_parent with [better performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220404/what-is-the-trick-with-0dip-layout-height-or-layouth-width).

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The TVs are way larger than the ETs.

Comment: Just invert the layout_weight, the point is that every line has same width for Labels & Text fields, isn't it?

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problems, glad it helped :)